# Hamming Weight to find the sum of 1 bits in the range between A and B inclusive

Tags: algorithms, logic, runtime-analysis

I am trying to find the sum of 1 bits in the range between **A** and **B** inclusive,

where -2^31 <= A <= B <= 2^31 - 1

**Input Format:**

The first line contains the number of test cases T (<=1000). Each of the next T lines contains two integers A and B.

I have used Hamming Weight algorithm to solve this problem. Though I have used memoization version of Hammnig Weight algorithm, it runs out of time.

```
mf = [-1 for i in range(65536)]

def count_1s(x):
    """It counts the number of 1 bits in an given 32 bit integer"""
    if (x > 65535):
        return count_1s(x&0xFFFF) + count_1s(x>>16)
    elif (mf[x] != -1):
        return mf[x]
    else:
        count = 0
        while(x > 0):
            x &= (x-1)
            count += 1
        mf[x] = count
        return mf[x]


t = int(input())

for i in range(t):
    a = [int(number) for number in input().split()]
    count = 0

    for j in range(a[0], a[1]+1):
        if (j < 0):
            count += 32 - count_1s(-j-1)
        else:
            count += count_1s(j)

    print(count)
```

So I am in a need of improving this algorithm. Are there any ways to improve this algorithm? or I should use some other algorithm to solve this problem?

**Link for Input:**

https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/56/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINGOTNJCTGAUP7NA&Expires=1416339544&Signature=5bf736TpbPUWcQZ%2FbGijtBHbVeM%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

**Required Output:**

https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/56/output02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINGOTNJCTGAUP7NA&Expires=1416339722&Signature=NUwWGdUVsvttRWx0janzsxncDtY%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Questions about improving programs is not ontopic here. If you have a question about your *algorithmic approach*, please refactor the question thus (pseudo code instead of source code, a natural language description of your approach, and why you doubt that it's as good as can be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is *not* to manually go over all numbers from $A$ to $B$. For example, suppose $A = 0$ and $B = 2^n-1$. The $k$th bit of a number in $\{0,\ldots,2^n-1\}$ is $1$ exactly half the time, so the total number of $1$s is $n2^{n-1}$. Similarly, if $A = x2^n$ and $B = x2^n + 2^n-1$ then the number of $1$s is $n2^{n-1} + 2^nH(x)$, where $H(x)$ is the Hamming weight of $x$. In the general case, you have to decompose the range $[A,B]$ into a small number of ranges of the form just described. You should be able to do this with at most $2n$ or so ranges, where $n$ is the length of $B$ in bits.